Not able to get latest version Azure Git in Pipeline
I have a Yaml pipeline with 2 stages, each stage containing one single job and multiple steps.
Each job is running on 'Azure Pipelines' with 'windows-latest' using runonce strategy combined with templates.
In the first stage I am checking out my git repo,update some files and commit those changes.
I'm doing the commit in powershell :
Write-Host "Fetch latest from git"
        git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" pull origin ${{parameters.Branch}}        
        Write-Host "commit all changes"
        git config user.email "${{parameters.GitUserEmail}}"
        git config user.name "${{parameters.GitUserName}}"
        git add --all
        git commit -m "${{parameters.commitMessage}}" 
        git tag v$(NewVersion)
        git tag -a manual-export -m "manual triggered export"        
        Write-Host "push tag to git"
        git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" push --tag
        Write-Host "push to code"
        git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" push origin ${{parameters.Branch}}

In the next stage, I try to get those last changes.
So I do a checkout (step) of my repo, this will download the files locally.
Unfortunately, it is not downloading the latest version, my HEAD remains on the second to last commit.
Also tried to force a pull using the code below, but still not fetching the last commit.
It reports this where d321994 is the second to last commit instead of the last commit.
branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.
Previous HEAD position was d321994 Daily Solution Commit
Switched to a new branch 'main'
Already up to date
Write-Host "Fetching latest repository changes..."
      Write-Host "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/VAB.PowerPlatform.ReleaseSolutions"
      git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" fetch --tags
      Write-Host "Checkout"
      git checkout ${{parameters.Branch}}
      Write-Host "Pull"
      git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" pull

I don't get it to be honest, what am I doing wrong here?
Regards,
Sven

I can reproduce the same situation. And I can confirm that this is an expected behavior.
When a pipeline is queued the ref is set. All Stages/jobs in the pipeline will checkout the same reference. This is how Pipeline works.

branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'. Previous HEAD position was d321994 Daily Solution Commit Switched to a new branch 'main' Already up to date

I can reproduce the same issue with your script.

To get the latest change in stage 2, you can use the following script:
   Write-Host "Fetching latest repository changes..."
   Write-Host "Pull"
   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
   git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" pull origin HEAD:${{parameters.Branch}} --allow-unrelated-histories
   Write-Host "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/VAB.PowerPlatform.ReleaseSolutions"
   git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" fetch --tags

YAML sample:
- stage: stage2
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
    - powershell: |
          Write-Host "Fetching latest repository changes..."
          Write-Host "Pull"
          git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
          git config --global user.name "Your Name"
          git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" pull origin HEAD:${{parameters.Branch}} --allow-unrelated-histories
          Write-Host "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/VAB.PowerPlatform.ReleaseSolutions"
          git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" fetch --tags

Result:

